# Specify plot width and height with ggplot and grid.arrange

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to combine different plots in ggplot with grid.arrange. I have data from two different groups that performed a different number tasks in an experiment. One group performed 2 tasks and the other group 4 tasks. I would like to plot the median response times of each group per task, and then combine these plots with the help of grid.arrange (via the command grid.arrange(plot1,plot2, ncol=2)) into one image (see image). The problem is now that the width of the left plot in the image is not the same as the width at the right plot in the image. Is there a way to specify the width of the plots in either ggplot or grid.arrange? I know this might be possible with the "cowplot" package in R but some reason I cannot install this package into my version (version 3.2.2 of Rstudio).

[These are the two plots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TuZuG.png)

Comment: The version of RStudio is irrelevant, but the version of R may be important. Any reason you cannot update R?

Comment: Can you install `cowplot` from source?

Comment: Also, `grid.arrange` takes the `heights` and `widths` arguments to set the sizes, though you need to tweak manually.

Comment: I did not know that there was a difference between updating Rstudio and R itself. I updated R and now cowplot does work. Thank you for your help!

Comment: R is the underlying programming language / statistics program. RStudio is a corresponding integrated development environment (IDE). However you don't need RStudio to run R programs. :-)